# How do I init my array to be scoped everywhere

Tags: swift

I m a bit confused about the declaration of the variable 'tb' that I want it scoped everywhere. This variable comes from a JSON.

If I init directly from the JSON

```
var tb = json as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

it's working, but it's not scoping to the tableView function.

I am still a swift beginner, so if someone can explain me how should i do ? and how this scope and the variable init/type are working , I would appreciate very much.

Here's the code:

```
class BiensViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var maTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var user = ""
    var tb:[Dictionary<String, Any>]
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //on récupère l'utilisateur courant.
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let urlRepDocuments =  try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let url = urlRepDocuments.appendingPathComponent("user.plist")
    print(url)
    if let dico = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: url.path){
        if dico["email"] != nil {
            user = dico["email"] as! String
        }
    }
    let parameters = ["email": user]
    //
    guard let httpUrl = URL(string: "https://mysite.000webhostapp.com/services")else{return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: httpUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print("******")
            print(response)
        }

        let json:Any
        if let data = data {
            do {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                //print(json)
                tb = json as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
                print(tb)


            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return tb.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //Récupéré une cellule réutilisable
        let cellule:BiensTableViewCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "maCellulePersonnalise", for: indexPath)
            as! BiensTableViewCell

        //peuple la cellule
        cellule.etqRef.text = tb[indexPath.row]["ref"] as? String
        cellule.EtqAdresse.text = tb[indexPath.row]["adresse"] as? String
        cellule.etqCP.text = tb[indexPath.row]["cp"] as? String
        cellule.etqVille.text = tb[indexPath.row]["ville"] as? String
        cellule.etqNomLoc.text = tb[indexPath.row]["nom"] as? String
        cellule.etqLoyer.text = tb[indexPath.row]["loyer"] as? String
        return cellule

}}}
```

the error is :

Variable 'tb' captured by a closure before being initialized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to declare the variable outside the viewDidLoad() just below where the outlets are drawn. Currently, your variable is just limited to the scope of viewDidLoad(). But now it will be accessible in complete class.

```
class BiensViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var maTable: UITableView!
var tb = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
//or you can use:-  var tb = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() according to your requirement
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. But I don't understant why those '()' at the end make the error disapear? Is it like a contructor ? but it's not a function, just a array declaration.
 And AnyObject or Any, wich one is better ? Any cover AnyObject? I mean AnyObject is inclued in Any? I mean AnyObject is just for objects? Am I right ? :p

Comment: Hi,
Firstly, use of () at the end makes error disappear because because this is an object oriented programming. In swift you have to initialise the variable before use and for initialisation all you have to do is ->    var tb: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]?
And In case of giving its type you don't have to place () in the end, but when you assign value to it using = operator, you are indirectly calling the init methods of class array that allocates it with some initial value. Hence to call the constructors of the class you place () at the ends.

Comment: Moreover, if we talk about AnyObject or Any

Swift provides two special types for working with nonspecific types:
Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.
AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
Moreover,
Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about the types you expect to work with in your code.

Comment: When you import Foundation or import UIKit or import Cocoa, it is possible to declare your array as [String: AnyObject], but in this case Swift is treating your Int, Double, Float literals as NSNumber, your Strings as NSString, your Arrays as NSArray, and your dictionaries as NSDictionary, all of which are objects. A dictionary using AnyObject as the value type is convertible to NSDictionary, but one using Any is not.